# ZfalseE_INFRA_1007Unsupported media type415 Unsupported Media type

Tags: xml

I am totally new to any form of programming and using Postman.

I am currently trying to get a machine ID and the Vulnerability associated with it.  I am using Qualys API.

So far I have manged to run a scan through the GUI and I have then managed to get the results via postman (yay). However when trying to get a specific machine ID and Vulnerability info I can not.

I seem to get **ZfalseE_INFRA_1007Unsupported media type415 Unsupported Media type**

I have no idea what these means. Apologies if a bit vague .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ServiceResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <completedAt>2017-10-20T08:28:25Z</completedAt>
    <success>false</success>
    <errorCode>E_INFRA_1007</errorCode>
    <errorReason>Unsupported media type</errorReason>
    <errorMessage>415 Unsupported Media type</errorMessage>
</ServiceResponse>
```

Comment: Try this, In the Headers of the call specify `"Content-Type: application/xml"`

Comment: Thanks, not worked. I have noticed under: 

key: id
Value: long

However long changes once i hit send to: long...

Comment: The error suggests the Accept or Content-Type headers you are passing in are not supported for the REST call.

Comment: Thanks, for the reply, apologies for my late response. I thought that was the case after further investigation.. Will try and find another way. Will keep you posted.